# Build Ribbon in full MVVM with Dot Net 4.5

Tags: wpf, mvvm, ribbon

we have several applications in **FULL** MVVM using the Ribbon from Microsoft. And it works fine, it's a great and flexible component :)

I was surprised to have to build my own templates and bindings to be able to use the ribbon in MVVM (I didn't find those files anywhere).

We are still using the Ribbon DLL from Microsoft (released around 2010 ) and can't switch to the ribbon existing in the Framework because it doesn't work with our Templates/bindings. Nothing happens/appears. Using the XAML description, everything is fine. I'm probably missing something. Does someone use it in full MVVM and which approach did you use to get it working ? Does the Framework contains the Templates and bindings hided somewhere ?

To summarize, how to use the ribbon included in the 4.5 Framework in **FULL** MVVM ?

Thanks for your help guys :)

Comment: Is this WPF?  If so you should add the "wpf" tag for better visibility.

Comment: Did you add a reference to System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon? Or what is your actual issue? Ribbon is a Control that has nothing to do with MVVM really.

Comment: Yes . It works using XAML. I just would like to get it working using MVVM. I can't believe that there is not an easy way to do it. I wrote 420 lines of XAML resources to get it working with the DLL. Not everyone do that I hope, or everyone don't care about MVVM Ribbon :)

Comment: "It works using XAML but it doesn't work using MVVM" makes no sense at all. XAML are used in all MVVM applications. So once again, what is your issue?

Comment: If I want to use it in MVVM, I have to define all ribbon templates/triggers, it's quite a lot of work before to be able to use the ribbon. I mean describing all ribbon components in XAML (Ribbon, RibbonTab, RibbonButton,....). This description doesn't work for the new Ribbon and must be done somewhere. No Template = no rendering.

Comment: Templating has nothing to with MVVM...and of course there is a default template for the Ribbon in .NET 4.5.

Comment: Great :). Do you know any article using full mvvm ribbon in 4.5 or the way to use it ? It's easy to find documentation for the first DLL released, not for the integrated ribbon in 4.5.

Comment: You should be able to use it more or less the same as you use your current version.

Comment: I agree. I guess I miss something and time is running out :). I may do a last try on Monday if no miraculous answers :). Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you target .NET Framework 4.5 or later you could add a reference to `System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon.dll` and use the built-in `RibbonControl` as-is:

```
<Ribbon />
```

You should be able to use this one more or less the exact same way as you use your current version. The templating of a control has nothing to do with MVVM. And of course the control comes with a default template.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you agree that I have to fill a view model with the same properties like the ones needed to render the ribbon. If this view model doesn't exist in the Framework I have to create it (many classes (27 in my case, I don't implement everything). And then I need to create all bindings between Ribbon controls and view model classes.

Comment: There are no view models in the framework...you create these. And you don't need a view model to simply render the Ribbon.

Comment: Microsoft didn't give us a dedicated VM with bindings, in order to be ready to use ???

Comment: No. They gave you the control. How you use the control is up to you. I recommend this article on MVVM: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848246.aspx

Comment: I'm sry you both don't get me, :). eg, I created a class TabViewModel with properties : Header, IsSelected, KeyTip, ContextualTabGroupHeader, DataCollection. Then I'll have to bind this view model to ribbon control. It's a huge work. For my company developpers I did the work. They can quickly do MVVM ribbon with the old DLL... I'm surprised it's not straightforward

Comment: Or you could simply set the properties of the control itself. Again, it is up to you. But to answer your question; No, there is no view model included in the framework.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'll try to fix it.

Comment: I programmed it out in pure MVVM. Check this: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1d2OckuDTLwnZ86p50Keyh_67zz2eWwFC/view?usp=sharing